# Mysql IN keyword taking as List as String

Tags: mysql, mariadb

@posts_tags variable will have comma separated values of ids ex: 1,2,3,4 and IN keyword is taking it as a complete string. It shows only results of first id in @posts_tags.

IN(1,2,3,4) works fine but IN('1,2,3,4') will shows results of 1, why ?

NOTE: There is no limitation of results due to LIMIT and I cannot use FIND_IN_SET because it is not working with partition pruning.

`posts_tags` is text field in `users_preferences` table.

```
SELECT  `posts_tags` INTO @posts_tags
FROM `users_preferences` 
WHERE `user_id` = 12;

SELECT
posts.post_id,
posts.owner_id

FROM `posts_main` AS posts
WHERE
posts.tag_id IN(@posts_tags)
ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I created a Many to Many table that stores tags(INT) selected by user(INT), and placed a subquery inside IN still what is inside IN is considered as String not Integers List.

Comment: Parse your CSV to separate values. For example, use JSON_TABLE(). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06394100250235fc682ecd892823c7fc

Answer (score 0):

When not used in subqueries the IN operator is a replacement for one or more OR operators:

`SET @a:=2`

`SELECT @a in (1,2,3,4)` is a shorthand for
`SELECT @a=1 OR @a=2 OR @a=3 OR @a=4`

Since you store multiple values in a string, the string it self will be used as a single value:

`SELECT @a IN ("1,2,3,4")` is equivalent for
`SELECT @a= "1,2,3,4"`

**Hint:**
Usually you will get the transformed statement by executing `SHOW WARNINGS` after running `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

```
>explain extended select @a IN ("1,2,3,4");
  (output skipped)

> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | select @`a` = '1,2,3,4' AS `@a IN ("1,2,3,4")` |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this with the following and partition pruning is working like wonders.

```
BEGIN
SELECT `posts_tags` INTO @posts_tags FROM `users_preferences` WHERE `user_id` = 12;

PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT("EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT posts.post_id,posts.owner_id FROM `posts_main` AS posts WHERE posts.tag_id IN(" ,@posts_tags, ") ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC;");

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```